# Aurora MySql Default USAGE privileges on every newly created user

Tags: privileges, amazon-aurora

It seems that when creating a new user, a default "USAGE" privilege is granted on EVERY database without any way to revoke these "usage" privileges.

steps to reproduce:

```
CREATE USER 'mynewuser'@'%' 
IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx';
flush privileges;
```

then

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mynewuser';
>    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mynewuser'@'%'
```

Trying to revoke:

```
REVOKE USAGE ON *.* FROM 'mynewuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mynewuser';
>    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mynewuser'@'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think you have an incorrect understanding of the `USAGE` privilege.

> This privilege specifier stands for “no privileges.” It is used at the
>   global level with GRANT to modify account attributes such as resource
>   limits or SSL characteristics without naming specific account
>   privileges in the privilege list. **SHOW GRANTS displays USAGE to**
>   **indicate that an account has no privileges at a privilege level.**

Comment: Maybe i missed something but the problem is that this user has  a ‘usage’ privilege on every databases on this instance. So how could we figure it out ? Thanks

Comment: Let me rephrase my statement into a question: What issue are you seeing about having the 'USAGE' privilege?

Comment: I’ve never granted any privilege on this user.

Comment: Yes, because that is granted by default when you created the user. And you still haven't explained what is the issue of having the grant, aside from the fact that  "you did not grant it". Again, my answer has the explanation from MySQL, what the grant is for and that it should not be a cause of worry.

Comment: Ok sorry for that, my problem is that this user can view, use select on any existing dbs.tables of that instance. I was thinking that it was related to this usage privilege but regarding your response (and the doc) it’s not. What  could make this possible ?